# OWIN mapping inside of middleware

Tags: c#, owin

I want to map a url inside of my middleware but the code never executes and I always get a 404 error. If I do the same exact thing outside of my middleware everything works as expected. How do I register a mapping from inside my middleware?

see comments in code below:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    internal void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(TestMiddleware), app);

        // this works just fine: http://myapp/test
        app.Map("/test", config =>
        {
            config.Run(context =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("<html><body>test</body></html>");
            });
        });
    }

    class TestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public TestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app)
            : base(next)
        {
            app.Map("/yup", config =>
            {
                config.Run(context =>
                {
                    // this never executes. always 404 error: http://myapp/yup
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                    return context.Response.WriteAsync("<html><body>yup</body></html>");
                });
            });
        }

        public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            return base.Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in that constructor? Are you sure it's being called while OWIN is still ready to do configuration? I don't actually know how disjoint its config stage is, but I wouldn't be surprised if it had to all be done at the beginning, and I'm not sure whether this would qualify, since you aren't calling the constructor directly.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Looks like the break point in the middleware constructor is fired well after everything in `Startup.Configure()` has executed. I need to create an extension method to register my middleware and my additional mappings can piggy-back off that.

Comment: Cool. That was a total shot in the dark :P. But yeah, I find extension methods are a nice way to handle that kind of thing, even aside from this issue. So that might not be so bad, anyway.